# Determine free memory available in JavaScript for iPhone web app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cordova, mobile-safari

We understand there is something like a 10 MB memory allocation limit for JavaScript per app in a UIWebView.

To avoid exceeding the limit, it would be nice to know how much memory our app is consuming, or how much memory is left before we exceed the allocation limit.

Is there a way to do this?

We're using PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have Xcode with a setup similar to:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html

You can run Instruments, the profiler (in Xcode: Product > Profile), to check what's the memory usage of your application tracing "Allocations".